# Proof: Identity with integral

Tags: integration

Consider:

$$1-e^{at} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(at)^k}{k!} = \int_0^t \frac{a^k}{(k-1)!}x^{k-1}e^{-ax}dx$$

How do I get to the right?

Comment: Derivate both side of the equality...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Take the derivative $\frac{d}{dt}$ of both sides and invoke the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Then I get for the right side: $\frac{a^k}{(k-1)!} t^{k-1}e^{at}$. On the left I still have this sum.

Comment: @Alif You don't have a sum on the left hand side. You have to apply the product rule on the left hand side and you will be able to cancel the largest parts of the sums, ending up with what you want.